How to switch between a mock and a real implementation of some software system in FastAPI test code
I am writing a FastAPI application which provides a REST interface for some software system.
I have written two implementations of this software system using a Strategy Pattern.
To illustrate by way of example, here is a MWE code for an example of a similar, but simplified Strategy Pattern. In this example, I have used the concept of a database wrapper class.
The DatabaseWrapperReal class is incomplete, and in reality would use something like sqlalchemy to talk to a real database.
The DatabaseWrapperFake class simply provides a mock get function which returns some predetermined data for testing purposes.
# Software System (library) Code

class DatabaseWrapperReal():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def get(self, key: str) -> str:
        # pseudo-implementation. the real implementation of this would
        # connect to a database and query it
        return f'value'

class DatabaseWrapperFake():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._data = {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': 'value2',
            'key3': 'value3',
        }

    def get(self, key: str) -> str:
        return self._data[key]

class DatabaseWrapper():
    def __init__(self, test_mode: bool = False) -> None:
        if test_mode:
            self._database_wrapper = DatabaseWrapperFake()
        else:
            self._database_wrapper = DatabaseWrapperReal()

    def get(self, key: str) -> str:
        return self._database_wrapper.get(key)

The following code shows how I use a DatabaseWrapper in the FastAPI code. I initialize it using test_mode=False. This is fine for normal use, but test_mode should be set to True for testing purposes.
# FastAPI code

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

from database_wrapper import DatabaseWrapper

test_mode = False
database_wrapper = DatabaseWrapper(test_mode=test_mode)

app = FastAPI()

class Key(BaseModel):
    key: str

@app.post('/get_by_key')
def get_by_key_endpoint(key: Key):
    key = key.key
    value = database_wrapper.get(key=key)
    return {
        'value': value,
    }

Finally, here is an example of some test code.
# FastAPI Tests Code

from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from fastapi_webserver_database_wrapper import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_fastapi_webserver_database_wrapper():

    data = {
        'key': 'key1',
    }
    response = client.post('/get_by_key', json=data)
    print(response.json())
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {
        'value', 'value1',
    }

Currently, the test does not pass. It fails, because the test_mode variable is still set to False when the test is run. This means that instead of using the DatabaseWrapperFake class, the DatabaseWrapper Strategy uses the real implementation, DatabaseWrapperReal.
Am I structuring my code in the correct way?

Should I initialize the database_wrapper as a global variable from within the FastAPI code?
Should I use a parameter in the constructor of the DatabaseWrapper class to switch between the two Strategies?
Assuming the answer to the above questions is "yes", how should I switch to the Fake implementation Strategy in the test code? (If the above answers are "no" this question is no longer relevant.)


Use FastAPI's built-in dependency system: Depends - you can then swap your dependency based on whether you're running in test mode or not by using override_dependencies in your application. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/ and https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/

How is test_mode passed into the app? I have a similar setup, but in my case the app reads in a set of configs from the environment. So, when running the real app, it reads in real configs (test_mode is false), and when running in tests, it reads in test configs (test_mode is true). The main app modules naturally gets configured based on configs, and I never have to mock anything in the tests.
